# Trying to prove ratio test : stuck on proving the $\gamma \leq 1 \leq \alpha$ case

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm trying to prove the ratio test but I'm stuck on proving the $\gamma \leq 1 \leq \alpha$ case.

Let's start with the theorem.
Let the sequence $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ for $n \geq 1$. Let the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$.
We define :
\begin{equation}
    \alpha \equiv \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sup{\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|}
  \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \gamma \equiv \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \inf{\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|}
  \end{equation}

Then 3 cases are possibles

- $\alpha < 1 \implies \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |a_n| < +\infty$. The series converge absolutely.
- $\gamma > 1 \implies \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ diverge.
- $\gamma \leq 1 \leq \alpha \implies$ we cannot conclude.

My proof attempt :

- For $\alpha < 1$ :

Let $\beta > 0$ such that $\alpha < \beta < 1$. $\exists N \geq 1$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| <\beta$. Otherwise if $n \geq N$ and $\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| \geq \beta$ there would be infinity of $n$.

By recurrence,
\begin{equation}
      |a_{n+1}| \leq |a_n| (\beta) \implies |a_n| \leq |a_N| (\beta)^{n-N}, \quad \forall n \geq N
\end{equation}
Because $\beta < 1$ we have,
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |a_N| (\beta)^{n-N} = |a_N| \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (\beta)^{n-N} < +\infty
\end{equation}
Then by comparison test,
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n
\end{equation}
converge absolutely.

- For $\gamma > 1$ :

Let $\beta > 0$ such that $1 < \beta < \gamma$. $\exists N \geq 1$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| > \beta$.

By recurrence,
\begin{equation}
  |a_{n+1}| > |a_n| (\beta) \implies |a_n| > |a_N| (\beta)^{n-N}, \quad \forall n \geq N
\end{equation}
Because $\beta > 1$ we have,
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |a_N| (\beta)^{n-N} = |a_N| \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (\beta)^{n-N}
\end{equation}
diverge and then by comparison test,
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n
\end{equation}
diverge too.

- For $\gamma \leq 1 \leq \alpha$ :

That's where I'm stuck. I guess I should find 2 sequences such that $\gamma \leq 1$ and $\alpha \geq 1$ and such that one series converge and the other diverge but I didn' find these two. Any ideas ?

Comment: An idea $a_{2n+1}=2a_{2n},a_{2n}=a_{2n-1}/3$.

Comment: The standard example $a_n = 1/n$ and $a_n = 1/n^2$ both have $\liminf{\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|} = \limsup{\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|} = 1$.